# unable to send email to other user emails account in django

Tags: django, sendgrid, django-email

i previously i was using gmail smtp to send mail**(working fine)** but now i created new account in sendgrid and im using free plan in my django project this my complete setting about send grid

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' # this is API key
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

**is any other settings required??** i am testing email using rest auth lib `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/password/reset/`

is show msg like `success": "Password reset e-mail has been sent."`

but **recipient did not received any mails** but in sendgrid dashboard it is showing 9 or 10 etc msg delivered

Comment: how are you sending email ? post the view

Comment: i am using EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' it is up to django rest frame work to send mail im not writting any send mail fiunction

Comment: i just changed setting gmail smtp to send grid smtp

Comment: why i am using send grid becuase amazon ses it taking more time  moved out of the sandbox its been week still resources email my case is not resolved

Comment: solution: sorry i was getting mail in spam folder

Comment: Might want to erase your api key. Anybody who sees it can use your account.

Comment: It is better to change your api key because it is now in the history of the question.